# Django Rest Framework retrieves empty values instead of null when using Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest Framework, so when i insert a field with null value [POST Model], it retrieves it with an empty value [Get Object Detail]. Why does it happen?

Comment: Saudações, Bruno. Estamos no [pt.so], então poderia traduzir sua pergunta? Aproveite e leia o guia de [ask] para verificar como fazer uma boa pergunta.

Comment: Aproveite também e faça o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour).